# "Reverse search" in MySQL - Find matching needles (in DB) from a submitted haystack

Tags: mysql, search, reverse

I want to be able to locate existing needles (that are stored as database entries) based on a user-submitted haystack.

For example...

In the database there are the following entries:
'catching fire', 
'ghostbusters', 
'jay and silent bob', 
'terminator 2'

If I then 'submit' a haystack of "hunger games catching fire" I would like it to pick out the 'catching fire' database entry - because that needle is present in my submitted haystack. I would describe this as a 'reverse search' although it may not be the correct phrase...!!

Is this possible without having to iterate through every single 'needle' in the database?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to do this type of reverse search without doing a table-scan.

The search would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM needles 
WHERE 'hunger games catching fire' LIKE CONCAT('%', title, '%');
```

Or else use regular expression word-boundary patterns:

```
SELECT * FROM needles 
WHERE 'hunger games catching fire' RLIKE CONCAT('[[:<:]]', title, '[[:>:]]');
```

Comment: Thanks Bill. I'll give this method a try.